# Regex in Swagger/OpenAPI path and AWS API

Tags: swagger, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I am having issue with regex in openapi path. There's required path parameter in API, that must be ***proxy+***. The problem is when I try to import openapi file to AWS API with ***proxy+*** parameter it returns error because of regex (path parameters can't have "+" symbol).

*(Before posting this question I searched StackOverflow and current posts don't answer my question. I know that path parameters are limited by regex, I am searching for solution in case of "proxy"-"proxy+" and difference of errors in swagger editor and AWS)*

That's how it looks like.

1. This code returns no errors in swagger editor, but doesn't want to import in AWS API, because of regex:

```
paths: 
  /test/{tablename}/{proxy+}:
    options:
      parameters:
      - name: "tablename"
        in: "path"
        required: true
        schema:
         type: "string" 
      - name: "proxy+"
        in: "path"
        required: true
        schema:
         type: "string"
```

AWS error from CLI:

> Unable to put method 'OPTIONS' on resource at path
>   '/test/{tablename}/{proxy+}': Invalid mapping expression specified:
>   Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Parameter name should
>   match the following regular expression: ^[a-zA-Z0-9._$-]+$]

2. I tried to remove "+" from proxy parameter, but kept it in the path this way:

```
paths: 
  /test/{tablename}/{proxy+}:
    options:
      parameters:
      - name: "tablename"
        in: "path"
        required: true
        schema:
         type: "string" 
      - name: "proxy"
        in: "path"
        required: true
        schema:
         type: "string"
```

In this case AWS imports works without error, but swagger editor returns this error:

> Semantic error at paths./test/{tablename}/{proxy+} Declared path
>   parameter "proxy+" needs to be defined as a path parameter at either
>   the path or operation level

What possible solution would you recommend in this case?

Why swagger editor errors and AWS API import errors differ?